# I purchased the Windows 10 Minecraft for Xbox, can I play it on Windows 7 pc?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to get Minecraft on my pc so I can mod. I have paid for it on Xbox, but it's saying I need to buy it again. I am on Windows 7 so I don't know if that is a problem or not.

Comment: You could try to get a refund if you're fast with it. The "Java edition" works on all computers and is generally better.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. I tried with the Nintendo Switch and it doesn't work either. You have to buy it separately(I know, what a rip!).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using the "Bedrock Edition", which only works on XBox, Playstation, and Windows10, and also suffers from less support with mods. The cheapest option would be to purchase a copy of Minecraft "Java Edition", which is the main edition for PC, and mod that, as purchasing a copy of Win10 is upwards of $100.

Comment: *Only works on Xbox, Playstation, Mobile, Switch, Windows 10